# Understanding neighborhood subbasis

Tags: general-topology

I came across the following definition.

Definition
Let $(S,\tau)$ be a topological space and $x \in S$. Let $\mathcal{B}(x) $ be a set of neighborhoods of $x$.
We say that $\mathcal{B}(x)$ is a neighborhood subbasis of $x$ iff for every neighborhood $N$ of $x$, there exists a finite subset $\mathcal{K}(x)$ of $\mathcal{B}(x)$ such that $\cap \mathcal{K}(x) \subseteq N$.

I do not really understand why a neighborhood subbasis is defined as it is. Here is some context.

Regarding neighborhoods I know the neighborhood system of $x$, $\mathcal{N}(x)$, consisting of all neighborhoods of $x$. Since every superset of a neighborhood is also a neighborhood one can reduce the neighborhood system to neighborhood basis. Where $\mathcal{P}(x)$ is a neighborhood basis of $x$, if for every $N \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ there exists a $V \in \mathcal{P}$ such that $V \subseteq U$.

So there is a reason why one reduces a neighborhood system to a neighborhood basis. So my first question is, why do we further reduce a neighborhood basis to a neighborhood subbasis.

If I do understand the definition of neighborhood subbasis, we can generate the neighborhood basis by considering all finite intersections of elements in the neighborhood subbasis. Second question: Why do we use intersection and in particular why finite intersections.